# Special alarm application

Tags: android

I need an alarm application for specific time of every hour. For example, if I set the alarm value at 25, the alarm will go off at 25th min of every hour.ie 11:25am, 12:25pm, 1:25pm, 2:25pm etc. Is it possible? or is there an application, preferably android that has such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible with [repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). you can set alarm to fire at exact time with `setRepeating()` and the alarm's interval set to every hour and `RTC_WAKEUP` alarm type(Wakes up the device to fire the pending intent at the specified time). there are some examples in the first link.